# How to data-bind views per API level?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, backwards-compatibility

The requirement is *not* to display a bio-metric login button < API level 26 , because it isn't supported and therefore can be hidden for certain. method `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` is not an option, because the  data-binding should configure the view all by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to import `android.os.Build.VERSION` and `android.view.View`, in order to have constants `VERSION.SDK_INT` and class `View` available in the generated data-binding classes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="android.os.Build.VERSION"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>

    <!-- only visible on API >= 26 -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:visibility="@{VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        android:id="@+id/button_biometric_authentication"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_white_36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</layout>
```