# I need to show a toast message on every Friday

Tags: java, android

I want to show a text message in a textview on every friday of the week, and hide it all other days, it displays the whole day on fridays, and hide on all other days. How can i implement this, I have not tried any code since i do not know where to start from. Any example code?

Comment: If you haven't tried, why should stack overflow community?
Generally you have to save somewhere, if the toast was shown this friday. preferably with date. where to save it? probably in some app storage on local phone.
Once that is done, just simple condition needs to be satisfied for the toast to appear. How to do that? There are plenty of stack overflow answers for it.

Comment: `... on every friday of the week ...` How many Fridays do you have in a week?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps store the last time the message was displayed in the app's preferences, and then only display the message on Fridays if the previous display time was on a different day.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Calendar noticeDisplayTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    noticeDisplayTime.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong("noticeDisplayTime", 0));

    if (!(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == noticeDisplayTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) &&
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == noticeDisplayTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        prefs.edit().putLong("noticeDisplayTime", calendar.getTimeInMillis()).apply();
        // Display the notice
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `WorkManager` to schedule a `PeriodicWorkRequest` which displays a `Notification` (in order to provide you with the proper search terms). I use this to test my `WorkManager` schedules, which do not display any notifications in release mode. The reason is, that `Toast` is always silent - while these I can hear, eg. even when streaming music, because the stream audio ducks away.

Comment: Ok, i have been think of a text message in textview, i want to show  a textview on friday the whole day and hide it all other days, show it again on next friday and hide when friday passes, do you have any sample code for your suggestion

Comment: @tinoe one question per question (...). even data-binding `android:visibility` to some condition "is Friday" could already accomplish that, without scheduling workers.

Comment: Do you have any example code? You might assist, i am learning

Comment: your request for "gimme teh codes" is redundant, if you would have read what I've wrote. won't provide it because I'm too lazy to rewrite it, because it is not generic code - and most of all, because you're apparently to lazy to search for the terms provided - and haven't provided a single line of "having tried". telling how it works is fair enough.

Comment: Ok i appreciate your suggestion

Comment: @tinoe sorry, can't just start editing something which is irrelevant to me - while having to solve an actual problem, which is relevant for a commercial project. here would be an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824896/how-to-data-bind-views-per-api-level) of how you could bind that `TextView`; it just needs `Calendar` as import and the `if` condition adjusted.