# Why is DataBinding View Visibility not working

Tags: android, visibility, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I have the following DataBinding setup, but whenever "isPrivate" is true, the visibility stays View.GONE

**layout.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:binding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_1">

    ... 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_car_private"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lock"
        binding:visibility="@{viewModel.car.isPrivate}" />

   ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.app.MyViewModel" />
</data>

</layout>
```

**Activity**

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main).also { binding ->
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    binding.viewModel = myViewModel
}
```

**BindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("visibility")
fun setVisibility(view: View, isVisible: Boolean) {
    Timber.d("+++ isPrivate: $isVisible")
    view.visibility = if (isVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

- `@xml/scene_1` is not referencing the ImageView
- If I remove the `binding:visibility` line, the View is visible
- The LogOutput in the BindingAdapter always prints correct true/false values
- I also tried to add `binding.invalidateAll()` in the Activity setup, but no difference

**UPDATE:**

- the same BindingAdapter is used by another RecyclerView (its items) and works
- if I fake the invisibiliy with the following BindingAdapter, the imageResource is set corretly (the rest of the code is identical!)

```
    @BindingAdapter("isPrivate")
    fun setIsPrivate(imageView: ImageView, isPrivate: Boolean) {
        if (isPrivate) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lock)
        } else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
        }
    }
```

Comment: rootview and binding in activity is different ? I think instead of rootView ,binding should come. DataBindingUtil.setContentView() will return ActivityMainBinding.

Comment: ah sorry, that's a typo. I actually dont need the rootView.I edited the question.

Comment: Change the order of the variable assignment, first you assign viewmodel to your binding variable (`binding.viewModel = myViewModel`) and then set `binding.lifecycleOwner = this`.

Answer (score 1):

One can bind `boolean` values more simple with the ternary operator:

```
android:visibility="@{car.isPrivate ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

This is how I usually inflate them in a `Fragment` (for `fragment_main.xml`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mDataBinding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    if (this.mDataBinding != null) {
        Car item = ...
        this.mDataBinding.setCar(item);
    }
}
```

The actual beauty of data-binding is to have that generated, instead of having to write it - a `BindingAdapter` is only required for more complex operations, or certain attributes not being supported by default.

Comment: I also tried the inline logic. makes no difference. I simplified the code a bit and chose "object" as word for the data-bound field in the viewModel. I changed it to "car"

Comment: @muetzenflo you might have to import `View` in `<data />`, else it likely cannot generate the binding. here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824896/how-to-data-bind-views-per-api-level), where I'm certain that it works. `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` might another possible reason, because I usually inflate with it (no XML filename required).

Comment: importing `View` is not needed, because I don't use the inline xml-logic. The visibility is set in the BindingAdapter which knows about `View` anyway.
How else would I inflate a <layout> in an Activity? As far as I know you can use the `inflate()` methods in fragments only. Also, don't forget that all the other bindings in this layout are woking perfectly...this is the strangest part of the story...

Comment: @muetzenflo then just keep on with what you're trying to accomplish... have explained it in detail, while I'm not exactly a friend of ignorance. it's so simple, unless adding all that useless complexity and complaining it doesn't work.

Comment: Dont get me wrong..I am grateful for your input, but I tried all that already without success. I tried putting the if-else in the xml and importing `View`. No success. I tried using another way of inflating the ViewDataBinding, but it's not possible in an Activity. Why am I ignorant...?

Comment: @muetzenflo updated my answer, while removing some more complexity. unless importing `Car` and setting it to the data-binding, this might not behave as expected - in your other example, where it works, there might not be a nested `Object` either. and still, a `BindingAdapter` is overkill for what fits into a single line - and can be represented without having one.